# Should I use the class name or `cls` param to construct a an instance?

Tags: python

As title described, I an confused as the example:

```
class Point(object):

    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    @classmethod
    def get_point1(cls, cor): # cor is list with x=1 and y=2
        return Point(cor[0], cor[1])

    @classmethod
    def get_point2(cls, cor):
        return cls(cor[0], cor[1])
```

I am confused which one(`get_point1` or `get_point2`) should I use, and what is the difference between them?

Comment: Think about what happens if you subclass `Point` and call each of those methods on the subclass. Which you should use depends on which behaviour you want.

Comment: `cls()` is preferred, as it will allow you to extend that class.  For example, `class SpecialPoint(Point): pass`.  Currently, `SpecialPoint.get_point1(cor)` will create a `Point` object while `SpecialPoint.get_point2(cor)` will create a `SpecialPoint`.

Comment: Thanks, is there other difference except for subclass?

Comment: One might be if you end up changing the name of the class in the future, you only need to change it once (at the top) and not also in each of the classmethods.

Comment: `cls()` definitely makes sense if you're going to subclass `Point`. It might make sense if you think you might eventually subclass it. If neither of those things is the case it is more explicit and readable to use the `Point()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The @classmethod decorator makes the function a **class method**, as opposed to instance method. To make it more robust, it is preferable to use `cls` rather than the actual class name where it is defined.

If you use **cls**, the parameter which will be passed depends on the actual class being called (for example, if you subclass Point) while using **Point** explicity, may cause issues if you subclass it and use the class method.

Look at this code for example

```
class Point(object):

    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    @classmethod
    def get_point1(cls, cor): # cor is list like [1,2] with x=1 and y=2
        return Point(cor[0], cor[1])

    @classmethod
    def get_point2(cls, cor):
        return cls(cor[0], cor[1])


class SubPoint(Point):
    pass


sub1 = SubPoint.get_point1([0, 1])
sub2 = SubPoint.get_point2([2, 2])

print sub1.__class__
print sub2.__class__

<class '__main__.Point'>
<class '__main__.SubPoint'>
```

**Is there any other difference?** - well, if you need to do some logic inside your class method, which depends on class attributes, then yes it does.