# How to pick up the correct class (NameError)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-variables

I have been working on a project where I want to gather the urls and then I could just import all the modules with the scraper classes and it should register all of them into the list.

I have currently done:

```
import sys
import tldextract


class Scraper:
    scrapers = {}

    def __init_subclass__(scraper_class):
        Scraper.scrapers[scraper_class.url] = scraper_class # .url -> Unresolved attribute reference 'url' for class 'Scraper' 

    @classmethod
    def for_url(cls, url):
        k = tldextract.extract(url)
        return scrapers[k.domain]() #<-- Unresolved reference 'scrapers' 


class BBCScraper(Scraper):
    url = 'bbc.co.uk'

    def scrape(s):
        print(s)
        # FIXME Scrape the correct values for BBC
        return "Yay works!"


url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/'
scraper = Scraper.for_url(url)
scraper.scrape("yay")
```

My currently problem right now is that I am not able to continue to execute the code as I am not able to return `scrapers[k.domain]()`

```
Output >>> NameError: name 'scrapers' is not defined
```

I wonder how I can pick up the correct class as for exaple if the URL is the bbc, it should g into the BBCScraper class and then we call the scrape which later on will return the values that has been scraped on that specific website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as you did in `__init_subclass__` or use `cls.scrapers`.

```
@classmethod
def for_url(cls, url):
    k = tldextract.extract(url)
    return Scraper.scrapers[k.domain]() 
    # or
    return cls.scrapers[k.domain]()
```

---

As for the second issue

1. Please ask that in a separate question
2. Please explain better what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: I will create a new question about the second one. I dont think it might fit in here correctly. What is the different between using cls.scraper and Scraper.scrapers? :)

Comment: [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46128935/913098) - this behaves differently when inheritance comes into play. This may affect you depending on the second issue. I think for this specific use-case, this won't matter.